# why i cant see my before pseudo element and idk why the after element stretches past the <a> element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Firstly idk why I cant see before element even after adding specific width and height

Second question is the after element exceeds past the /a> tag even though I added it a width of 100% and position relative.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.menuText{
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
}
.menuText ul li{
    padding-top: 2rem;
}
.menuText ul li::before{
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: .25rem;
    background-color: #000;
}
.menuText ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: .25rem;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="ham"></div>
        <div class="menuText">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">My Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      
</body>
```

And i want to achieve this [i want the before and after element to appear on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SMUr.png)
but the main point is i cant seem to make the after element just 50% of the length of the text

Comment: you are wrong on position 'relative', you need using 'absolute' whitch must refer to his parent relative position.

Answer (score 0):

For the ::before element, because the element is positioned relative, you cant have 100% as a height value, I have changed height and width for ::before to match the height of the ::after element

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.menuText{
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
}
.menuText ul li{
    padding-top: 2rem;
}
.menuText ul li::before{
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: .25rem;
    background-color: #000;
}
.menuText ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: .25rem;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="ham"></div>
        <div class="menuText">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">My Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      
</body>
```

How would you like the ::before element to look? you didn't provide an example so guessing this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i kinda fixed the before element by adding a `position: absolute`